# How to hide the debug bar in Contao

Tags: contao

The debug bar is causing problems with Javascript (including Moo Tools which uses the `$`, while we use JQuery).

How can the debug bar be disabled, but the debug mode left on.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following setting:

```
$GLOBALS['TL_CONFIG']['hideDebugBar'] = true;
```

Answer (score -2):

You can turn it off in "System -> Settings -> Global configuration -> Checkbox Enable debug"

Comment: That disabled the debug mode in general.